# how to select specific node sets in xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

The xslt I'm currently using generates all the tags on the root.
I need to get the `<row>` sets and `<config>` set.

Source Xml:

```
<root>
    <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
    <location>84</location>
    <meal>07:36</meal>
    <config>
        <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
        <location>84</location>
        <meal>07:36</meal>
        <checknumber>91339082011-03-30T07:36:12</checknumber>
    </config>
    <items>
        <row>
            <descriptor>7297364</descriptor>
            <qty>1</qty>
            <price>33</price>
            <value>33</value>
            <recordtype>1</recordtype>
            <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
            <location>84</location>
        </row>
        <row>
            <descriptor>7794473</descriptor>
            <qty>1</qty>
            <price>60</price>
            <value>60</value>
            <recordtype>1</recordtype>
            <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
            <location>84</location>
        </row>
    </items>
    <tenders>
        <row>
            <id>13</id>
            <value>117.99</value>
            <recordtype>2</recordtype>
            <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
            <location>84</location>
        </row>
    </tenders>
    <taxes>
        <row>
            <id>2</id>
            <value>8.25</value>
            <recordtype>3</recordtype>
            <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
            <location>84</location>
        </row>
    </taxes>
</root>
```

Attempted Xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="row/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired Output:

```
<root>
    <config>
        <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
        <location>84</location>
        <meal>07:36</meal>
        <checknumber>91339082011-03-30T07:36:12</checknumber>
    </config>
    <row>
        <descriptor>7297364</descriptor>
        <qty>1</qty>
        <price>33</price>
        <value>33</value>
        <recordtype>1</recordtype>
        <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
        <location>84</location>
    </row>
    <row>
        <descriptor>7794473</descriptor>
        <qty>1</qty>
        <price>60</price>
        <value>60</value>
        <recordtype>1</recordtype>
        <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
        <location>84</location>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>13</id>
        <value>117.99</value>
        <recordtype>2</recordtype>
        <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
        <location>84</location>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>2</id>
        <value>8.25</value>
        <recordtype>3</recordtype>
        <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
        <location>84</location>
    </row>
</root>
```

Comment: first use xpath to match the config element and within that do another xpath to match the config i.e. first match="/root/config" second should just be match="/items/config". xslt isn't my bag (I use c# and xpath queries quite regularly and they seem 'about' right to me though you have used wildcard(?) i.e. row/* which I assume means returns all things in row? also you probably need to specify root and work your way to the node OR you can use // in xpath to mean ANYWHERE in the doc.

Comment: xpath is what xslt uses to traverse the tree so do some reading on it (it's dead simple)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This short and simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "node()[not(self::root or ancestor-or-self::config or ancestor-or-self::row)]">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
    <location>84</location>
    <meal>07:36</meal>
    <config>
        <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
        <location>84</location>
        <meal>07:36</meal>
        <checknumber>91339082011-03-30T07:36:12</checknumber>
    </config>
    <items>
        <row>
            <descriptor>7297364</descriptor>
            <qty>1</qty>
            <price>33</price>
            <value>33</value>
            <recordtype>1</recordtype>
            <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
            <location>84</location>
        </row>
        <row>
            <descriptor>7794473</descriptor>
            <qty>1</qty>
            <price>60</price>
            <value>60</value>
            <recordtype>1</recordtype>
            <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
            <location>84</location>
        </row>
    </items>
    <tenders>
        <row>
            <id>13</id>
            <value>117.99</value>
            <recordtype>2</recordtype>
            <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
            <location>84</location>
        </row>
    </tenders>
    <taxes>
        <row>
            <id>2</id>
            <value>8.25</value>
            <recordtype>3</recordtype>
            <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
            <location>84</location>
        </row>
    </taxes>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<root>
   <config>
      <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
      <location>84</location>
      <meal>07:36</meal>
      <checknumber>91339082011-03-30T07:36:12</checknumber>
   </config>
   <row>
      <descriptor>7297364</descriptor>
      <qty>1</qty>
      <price>33</price>
      <value>33</value>
      <recordtype>1</recordtype>
      <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
      <location>84</location>
   </row>
   <row>
      <descriptor>7794473</descriptor>
      <qty>1</qty>
      <price>60</price>
      <value>60</value>
      <recordtype>1</recordtype>
      <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
      <location>84</location>
   </row>
   <row>
      <id>13</id>
      <value>117.99</value>
      <recordtype>2</recordtype>
      <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
      <location>84</location>
   </row>
   <row>
      <id>2</id>
      <value>8.25</value>
      <recordtype>3</recordtype>
      <postdate>2011-03-30</postdate>
      <location>84</location>
   </row>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Using and overriding the **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.
2. Proper use of the `ancestor-or-self::` axis.

Comment: An explanation of how this works would be great. Right now the solution is not very helpful to those who try to achieve similar yet different results.

Comment: @DaniilShevelev, The 2-point explanation in this answer refers to fundamental XSLT and XPath concepts, that are well-known to XSLT programmers. These are well explained in good books (@MichaelKay) and Pluralsight training courses -- in many pages and hours of videos. It would be impractical -- and nobody will allow these to be replicated here. I recommend reading such a good book and/or watching a Pluralsight training course on XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it. This xslt works for me.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="//row">
                <row>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="//config">
                <config>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </config>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is a much simpler and shorter solution (see my answer). You need to get accustomed of using and overriding the identity template -- this is one of the most fundamental XSLT design patterns.